# HTTPCache and MemoryCache cross dependency

Tags: c#, .net, cache

After asking a [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23129913/300996) about the two .NET caching systems taking dependencies on each other I gave implementing them a go. I posted them as my own answer there but before accepting the answer I'd like some second opinions on the implementations.

**HttpCacheChangeMonitor**

Allows ObjectCache items to take a dependency on HTTPCache

```
public class HttpCacheChangeMonitor : ChangeMonitor
{
    private readonly string _uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    private readonly string[] _httpCacheKeys;

    public override string UniqueId
    {
        get { return _uniqueId; }
    }

    public HttpCacheChangeMonitor(string httpCacheKey)
        : this(new[] { httpCacheKey }) { }

    public HttpCacheChangeMonitor(string[] httpCacheKeys)
    {
        _httpCacheKeys = httpCacheKeys;
        Initialise();
    }

    private void Initialise()
    {
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(_uniqueId, _uniqueId, new CacheDependency(null, _httpCacheKeys), DateTime.MaxValue, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, Callback);
        InitializationComplete();
    }

    private void Callback(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
    {
        OnChanged(null);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(
                _uniqueId + " notifying cache of change.", "HttpCacheChangeMonitor");
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(_uniqueId);
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
public class HttpCacheChangeMonitorTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void ChangeMonitorTest()
    {
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("ChangeMonitorTest1", "", null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(0,10,0), CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("ChangeMonitorTest2", "", null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0), CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
        using (MemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache("TestCache", new NameValueCollection()))
        {

            // Add data to cache
            for (int idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++)
            {
                cache.Add("Key" + idx, "Value" + idx, GetPolicy(idx));
            }

            long middleCount = cache.GetCount();

            // Flush cached items associated with "NamedData" change monitors
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove("ChangeMonitorTest1");

            long finalCount = cache.GetCount();

            Assert.Equal(10, middleCount);
            Assert.Equal(5, middleCount - finalCount);
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove("ChangeMonitorTest2");
        }
    }

    private static CacheItemPolicy GetPolicy(int idx)
    {
        string name = (idx % 2 == 0) ? "ChangeMonitorTest1" : "ChangeMonitorTest2";

        CacheItemPolicy cip = new CacheItemPolicy();
        cip.AbsoluteExpiration = System.DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
        cip.ChangeMonitors.Add(new HttpCacheChangeMonitor(name));
        return cip;
    }
}
```

**MemoryCacheDependency**

Allows HttpCache items to take a dependency on MemoryCache

```
public class MemoryCacheDependency : CacheDependency
{
    private readonly string _uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> _cacheKeys;
    private readonly MemoryCache _cache;

    public override string GetUniqueID()
    {
        return _uniqueId;
    }

    public MemoryCacheDependency(MemoryCache cache, string cacheKey)
        : this(cache, new[] { cacheKey }) { }
    public MemoryCacheDependency(MemoryCache cache, IEnumerable<string> cacheKeys)
    {
        _cache = cache;
        _cacheKeys = cacheKeys;
        Initialise();
    }

    private void Initialise()
    {
        var monitor = _cache.CreateCacheEntryChangeMonitor(_cacheKeys);
        CacheItemPolicy pol = new CacheItemPolicy{AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.MaxValue, Priority = CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable};
        pol.ChangeMonitors.Add(monitor);
        pol.RemovedCallback = Callback;
        _cache.Add(_uniqueId, _uniqueId, pol);
        FinishInit();
    }

    private void Callback(CacheEntryRemovedArguments arguments)
    {
        NotifyDependencyChanged(arguments.Source, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    protected override void DependencyDispose()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(
                   _uniqueId + " notifying cache of change.", "ObjectCacheDependency");
        _cache.Remove(_uniqueId);
        base.DependencyDispose();
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
public class MemoryCacheDependencyTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void CacheDependencyTest()
    {
        using (MemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache("TestCache", new NameValueCollection()))
        {
            cache.Add("HttpCacheTest1", DateTime.Now, new CacheItemPolicy {SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)});
            cache.Add("HttpCacheTest2", DateTime.Now, new CacheItemPolicy {SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)});

            // Add data to cache
            for (int idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++)
            {
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("Key" + idx, "Value" + idx, GetDependency(cache, idx), Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(0,10,0), CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null);
            }

            int middleCount = HttpRuntime.Cache.Count;

            // Flush cached items associated with "NamedData" change monitors
            cache.Remove("HttpCacheTest1");

            int finalCount = HttpRuntime.Cache.Count;

            Assert.Equal(10, middleCount);
            Assert.Equal(5, middleCount - finalCount);
        }
    }

    private static CacheDependency GetDependency(MemoryCache cache, int idx)
    {
        string name = (idx % 2 == 0) ? "HttpCacheTest1" : "HttpCacheTest2";

        return new MemoryCacheDependency(cache, name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall looks very good, clean and well done. I only see minor tiny little things...

#### Nitpick - "Initialise" vs "Initialize"

This is just a minor nitpick, but it's kind of jumping at me:

> ```
> private void Initialise()
> {
>     HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(_uniqueId, _uniqueId, new CacheDependency(null, _httpCacheKeys), DateTime.MaxValue, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, Callback);
>     InitializationComplete();
> }
> ```

I find it weird that a method called `Initialise()` is calling one that's called `InitializationComplete()` - I think for consistency it would be better named `Initialize()`.

Also the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.changemonitor(v=vs.110).aspx) for `InitializationComplete()` says it's *called from the constructor of derived classes to indicate that initialization is finished.* - you *are* calling it from within the constructor, and I'm not familiar with using the `ChangeMonitor` class but it might be clearer to have that call explicitly show up in the constructor (similar to how `InitializeComponents()` remains in a form's constructor no matter what):

```
public HttpCacheChangeMonitor(string[] httpCacheKeys)
{
    _httpCacheKeys = httpCacheKeys;
    Initialize();
    InitializationComplete();
}
```

But then again it's no biggie, the code is very clear and easy to follow.

---

#### Temporal Coupling

That said I like constructors that do very little, and this is what you've got here, but the `Initialise` method seems of very little use, and has temporal coupling with the setting of `_httpCacheKeys` - I mean, if your constructor looked like this:

```
public HttpCacheChangeMonitor(string[] httpCacheKeys)
{
    Initialise();
    _httpCacheKeys = httpCacheKeys;
}
```

I'd expect it to blow up. One way to eliminate the temporal coupling, would be to take the array as a parameter:

```
private void Initialize(string[] httpCacheKeys)
{
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(_uniqueId, _uniqueId, new CacheDependency(null, httpCacheKeys), DateTime.MaxValue, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, Callback);
    InitializationComplete();
}
```

...and then the order of operations doesn't matter anymore:

```
public HttpCacheChangeMonitor(string[] httpCacheKeys)
{
    Initialize(httpCacheKeys);
    _httpCacheKeys = httpCacheKeys;
}
```

---

(haven't looked at the test code)

Comment: Thanks Matt. On the first point using British English is automatic for me but I think you're right that consistency here is probably better. `InitializationComplete` is a toss up between explicitness and DRY. Initialize did have more use but I removed a couple of constructors so could probably revisit the need for it.